# ProcessEvents not on the main thread for WinRT

Tags: windows-runtime

I want to set a timer that emulates a thread that every few milliseconds, calls Dispatcher->ProcessEvents() while inside the main run loop, I'm just rendering and presenting.

In this article, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh994934.aspx, and near the bottom, it says, "As noted previously, you can also do this with a timer object that you have synchronized to the display device's refresh signal." I'm assuming this can be done since Microsoft has explicitly stated that it could be done.

However, when I attempt this method, if I cache the dispatcher and call dispatcher->ProcessEvents() from inside a periodic ThreadPoolTimer, the events don't get processed.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is pretty specific hackorama for DirectX apps.  Don't do this in a XAML app.

Comment: Yes, this is for DirectX applications.